# How to use navigator.app.exitApp() after navigator.notification.alert

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

```
receivedEvent: function (id) {
    if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
        navigator.notification.alert('NO NETWORK CONNECTION', null, 'Warning', 'OK');
        }
        else {
            window.open('my_web_site', '_self');
        }
}
```

how close aplication after button **OK**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the confirm method instead of alert to show a message.

```
receivedEvent: function (id) {
    if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) { 
        navigator.notification.confirm("NO NETWORK CONNECTION", function(e){navigator.app.exitApp();}, ["Warning"], ["Ok"])
    }
    else {
        window.open('my_web_site', '_self');
    }
}
```